# Extracting values from dictionary using list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Given a list of values e.g.

```
list1=[19, 25, 100]
```

and an index:

```
i = {'a': {10: 1}, 'b': {100: 3}, 'c': {19: 3, 25: 2, 26: 1, 28: 1, 30: 1}, 'd': {46:4, 100: 1}, 'e': {10: 1, 25: 1, 100: 1}, 'f': {4: 1, 19: 1}
```

What is the least expensive method (dealing with a much larger scale) with which I can look up a list value within the dict's first values, sum all of the second values of the value pairs belonging to the key it appears in and multiply this by the second value itself? I'd want these values to be collated in a structure like so.

```
{{19: [24, 2], 25: [16, 3], 100: [3, 3, 5]}}
```

where 24 = (3 * (3+2+1+1+1)) for example

Thank you.

Comment: ......what are you trying to do here?

Comment: @gr1zzlybe4r It's an info retrieval task. I'm trying to calculate tf.idf values here

Comment: Shouldn't `100` be `[9,3,5]`? as for `b`, `9 = 3 * 3`.

Comment: @Psidom Yes, apologies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a double loop solution by looping through the keys and dictionaries, and constructing the dictionary on the go:

```
result = {}
for k in list1:
    result[k] = []
    for v in i.values():
        if k in v:
            result[k].append(v[k] * sum(v.values()))

result
# {19: [24, 2], 25: [16, 3], 100: [9, 3, 5]}
```